# Suppose we define the definite integral using the following formula $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\dfrac{b-a}{2}\cdot\left(f(a)+f(b)\right)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we define the definite integral using the following formula $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\dfrac{b-a}{2}\cdot\left(f(a)+f(b)\right)$, for more accurate result for $c\in(a,b)$, $F(c)=\dfrac{c-a}{2}(f(a)+f(c))+\dfrac{b-c}{2}(f(b)+f(c))$. When c=$\dfrac{a+b}{2}$,$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\dfrac{b-a}{4}(f(a)+f(b)+2f(c))$

**There are following two questions based on the above info**

Q- If $f''(x)<0$,$\forall x\in (a,b)$ and $c$ is a point such that $a<c<b$ and $(c,f(c))$ is the point lying on the curve for which $F(c)$ is maximum, then find $f'(c)$.

My attempt is as follows:-

Writing $F(c)$ in terms of $x$

$$F(x)=\dfrac{(x-a)}{2}(f(a)+f(x))+\dfrac{b-x}{2}(f(b)+f(x))$$

If $F(x)$ is maximum at $x=c$, so $F'(c)=0$

$$F'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left((x-a)f'(x)+f(a)+f(x)-f(b)-f(x)+(b-x)f'(x)\right)$$
$$F'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(-af'(x)+bf'(x)+f(a)-f(b)\right)$$

$$F'(c)=0$$

$$F'(c)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(-af'(c)+bf'(c)+f(a)-f(b)\right)$$
$$f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

**But I am not using the fact $f''(x)<0$,$\forall x\in (a,b)$. Am I missing anything here?**

Q- If $f(x)$ is a polynomial and if $\lim_{t\to a}\dfrac{\int_{a}^{t}f(x)dx-\dfrac{t-a}{2}\left(f(t)+f(a)\right)}{(t-a)^3}=0$ $\forall$ $a$, then degree of $f(x)$ can atmost be

My attempt is as follows:-

$$\lim_{t\to a}\dfrac{\dfrac{t-a}{4}\left(f(t)+f(a)+2f\left(\dfrac{a+t}{2}\right)\right)-\dfrac{t-a}{2}\left(f(t)+f(a)\right)}{(t-a)^3}=0$$

$$\lim_{t\to a}-\dfrac{-\dfrac{t-a}{4}f(t)-\dfrac{t-a}{4}f(a)+\dfrac{t-a}{4}\cdot2f\left(\dfrac{a+t}{2}\right)}{(t-a)^3}=0$$

$$\lim_{t\to a}-\dfrac{-f(t)-f(a)+\cdot2f\left(\dfrac{a+t}{2}\right)}{(t-a)^2}=0$$

Applying L Hospital as we have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ form

$$\lim_{t\to a}-\dfrac{-f'(t)+f'\left(\dfrac{a+t}{2}\right)}{2(t-a)}=0$$

Applying L Hospital as we again have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ form

$$\lim_{t\to a}\dfrac{-f''(t)+\dfrac{1}{2}f''\left(\dfrac{a+t}{2}\right)}{2}=0$$

$$\dfrac{-f''(a)+\dfrac{f''(a)}{2}}{2}=0$$

$$\dfrac{-f''(a)}{4}=0$$
$$f''(a)=0$$

So atmost $f(x)$ can be linear

So I have confusion only in Q-$1$ where we didn't make use of the fact $f''(x)<0$,$\forall x\in (a,b)$ and still got the correct answer.